# C# image auto resizing

Tags: c#, image, background, resize

I have a small project of a small game, so i have a Form and form background set to for example image1.jpg
When i change the backgroudn to image2.jpg it auto-resizes it to 248x248 i think and then my background is small multiplied images..
My defaul image size is 700x700, same as the form is. THe commands are use are

```
Image myimage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\sdsd\Desktop\Iconscollection\images(2).jpg");
this.BackgroundImage = myimage;
```

So how exactly i make it to change instantly to 700x700?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
this.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @Striller There is nothing to be explained. The answer is giving you a hint, you could go and read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Striller Basically, this (the form) has a BackgroundImageLayout property.  The command here is setting that property to ImageLayout.Stretch.  ImageLayout is an enumeration that has several members including Zoom, Center, Tile, etc.